# JSF 1.2 - How to pass huge data between JSF applications

Tags: jsf-1.2

I have two JSF 1.2 applications running in the same weblogic server: App1.war & App2.war I have a requirement to call a jsf page in App2 from App1 page say, page3.xhtml. After entering the values in all the pages of App2 the control should come back to App1 page3.xhtml and I should be able to use the data entered in App2 pages.

I am able to call App2 jsf page from App1 using ExternalContext.redirect() method. But the problem that I am having is I am not able to access the managed session bean from other application? Since the data is huge I cannot also pass it as a GET request. I can only create a xml data with all the page values and try to transfer using HTTPSession but that is not working. Below is the code that I am using in App1

```
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    session.setAttribute("xml", xml);

    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext .getExternalContext();
    externalContext.redirect(url);
```

And in App2

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    session.getAttribute("xml"); ----> Returns null
```

How to pass huge data between JSF applications?